# Export variable inside class component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, export

Hello my need is to import a variable that is the respence of a redux action inside another js file, i drop an exemple here

file1.js

```
    class UserForm extends Component {
    this.state={
    test:false
    }
    
    getResponse = ()=> {
    const respose = this.props.actionRedux();
    this.setState({test:response})
    }
    render(){
         return (
               <button onclick = {this.getResponse}/>
                 )
             }
    }
```

file2.js

```
// i want to import `this.state.test` here 
export const test = this.state.test ? true : false
```

Any hint will be helpfull thank you

Answer (score 0):

Store the response of redux action in store and use that, let's say result is the redux store variable who is having action response.
And then just use that value in desired file with the help of mapStateToProps

Answer (score 0):

if you are dispatching action on store, then you need to connect the component to the store. look at https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: is there another way without using redux ?